# Need to know about app chooser in android

Tags: android, listview, view, picker, android-external-storage

I have a list of files in listview .. these files actually reside on sd card. Now i want to open these files by using an app picker. I.e if this file is an image it should show all applications in my phone that can open jpg type files in application chooser box.
How can i do this .. can someone give me any idea about it?
Any help is appreciated :)
Thanks in advance 
I found dis piece of code ..how can i use it in my application?

```
public class Redirector {
public static void showActivityWithChooser( Context context, int chooserLabelTitleId, Intent intent ) {
  try {
    context.startActivity( Intent.createChooser( intent, 
                 context.getResources().getString( chooserLabelTitleId )) );
  } catch( Exception e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public static void viewInExternalApplication( Context context, String url ) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(   Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
  intent.setData( Uri.parse( url ) );
  intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET );
  showActivityWithChooser( context, R.string.open_chooser_title, intent );
}
```

}

Comment: Jiya, good question, that means you want to develop something like dynamic chooser...right?

Comment: yes something like that to view my files pratik :)

Comment: In this case, you can use default chooser, because android will open application chooser as per your file by default, so I think no need to create custom chooser.

Comment: Ok pratik i will give u my email address in chat later

Comment: check code in the answer given by dhaval .. can i use this code to open any type of file or will it handle jpeg files only?

Comment: ok i will send u an email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/YOUR_PATH_TO_Images/";

 try {
            if (f.exists()) {
                File file = new File(path
                        + listViewArray.get(position).getImageName());
                Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),
                        "image/*");


                target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

                Intent intent1 = Intent.createChooser(target,
                        "Open With");

                startActivity(intent1);
            }

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Pdf found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can it view any type of file or jpeg only ?

Comment: haven't tried it. I use this code for PDF. Let me see and get back to you.

Comment: i need to view every type of file by using this code ... pdf,ppt,mp3,mp4 etc ...how can i do that?

Comment: check my updated answer. I changed "application/jpeg" to "image/*". I am also checking it, wait few mins, i'll let you know the correct format.

Comment: You can use the answer in the current format. It opens all the apps which can open images into app chooser. I tested on the device.

Comment: can't it open any other file type like audio or video?

Comment: is there any way that i can add file types target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),
                        "image/*"); Here

Comment: not that i know of. But let me try and help you. Does your video or audio file format differ? I mean are they either ".mp4" or vary?

Comment: they vary .. mp3 format is .mp3 and of video is .mp4

Comment: for audio, use "audio/*" and for video - "video/*". You can try to identify those formats and then choose relevant "target.setDataType("","")". Identify them by either saving the file type in array you use or try to extact the string after ".". Are you getting some idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54044/discussion-between-dhaval-and-sparrow).

Answer (score 1):

Just send the intent. Android will show an app chosser itself, if more than one app capable of showing the specified file type is installed, or start the app directly, if there's just one (or the user selected "always"/"remember my choice" in the app chooser)

Answer (score 1):

To get the applications that can successfully open a given intent you'll use the PackageManager. Simply construct the intent as above and then use this code to get the applications that can handle the intent.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
myIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
myIntent.setType("mp3");    

PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> info = manager.queryIntentActivities(myIntent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

This will give you all the information on the programs that can handle the intent, including icon, and packagename. You can then create a dialog box with these options and save the option the user chooses.

Answer (score 0):

1.This is question is related to [Mime type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html)

First get extenstion of file and set [type of mime used by element into list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setDataAndType%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
private String extenstionFile(String url) {
    if (url.indexOf("?")>-1) {
        url = url.substring(0,url.indexOf("?"));
    }
    if (url.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        String ext = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(".") );
        if (ext.indexOf("%")>-1) {
            ext = ext.substring(0,ext.indexOf("%"));
        }
        if (ext.indexOf("/")>-1) {
            ext = ext.substring(0,ext.indexOf("/"));
        }
        return ext.toLowerCase();

    }
}
```

Than open supported type of application list:-

```
MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton(); 
Intent newIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

//Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   String mimeType =   myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extenstionFile(getFile().toString()).substring(1));
   newIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(getFile()),mimeType);
   newIntent.setFlags(newIntent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
try {
    _context.startActivity(newIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(_context, "No handler for this type of file.", 4000).show();
}
```

Comment: i cant understand some part of ur code  as it is complex for me .. um a biginner actually :) but ur answer will solve my problem i think :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the file please check whic file is it (ex pdf , jpg) , After that create an ACTION_VIEW intent and set the type of intent according to selected file type. Now brocast the intent , System itself will show you the list of applications thats supports the viewing of yor file.

Check below link you will get better idea.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html